# PHP exeption show up

Tags: php, исключения

```
class Search
{
    private $search_string = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = Database::getInstance();

        // prepare search string
        $this->search_string = (isset($_GET['search']) && !empty($_GET['search']))? $_GET['search'] : null;
        if ($this->search_string === null) {
            throw new Exception(SEARCH_STRING_EMPTY, 99);
        }
        ...
    }
}
try {
    $search = new Search();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    ...
}
```

Передаю пустую строку, выкидываю ексепшен, выводится ошибка `php Exception: in ...` (на подобии ошибки PHP_NOTICE и.т.д.), дальше его ловит мой блок catch. Как от этого избавится?

На версии PHP 5.2 этого нету, а на php 5.4 есть...
Пользуюсь OpenServer-ом. `error_reporting(0);` прописан...

UPD: скрин проблемы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте разместить исключение внутри класса в функции __construct().

Comment: Я не понял сути вопроса. От чего избавиться вам нужно?

Comment: @ArchDemon Вылетает ошибка на странице "Exeption". Почему? Как исправить?

Comment: Ваше исключение чем-то ловится. Иначе было бы не просто Exception ... а Uncaught exception, то есть «необработанное исключение»

Comment: @ReinRaus совершенно верно, ловится. Но почему выводится Exeption как ошибка?

Comment: меня это `$this->search_string ===` напрягает. яб заменил на **empty**

Comment: @username, Спасибо за попытку, но к сожалению не дало не каких изменений. По поводу **empty** наступал на грабли с 0 и по этому предпочитаю использовать === это же "рнр" :-)

Comment: Подозрвеаю, что это настройка xdebug.skream или аналог.

Comment: @Etki дебаг отключен.

Comment: @Makarenko_I_V омг, да у вас на скриншоте стандартная xdebug'овая расцветка. Я бы, кхм, перепроверил.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904177/2908793

Comment: @Etki Извиняюсь, вы действительно оказались правы! Добавьте ваш ответ, что бы я мог его принять. Желательно добавьте в ответ также ссылку с подробным описанием если есть. Не знал что xdebug будет выводить exeption, которые перехватываться.

Comment: Или я не понял или бессмыслица. Зачем человеку про `xdebug` рассказывать. У него `notice` отрабатывает. Нужно найти где это. Автор, получилось найти?

Comment: @borodatych, это был вывод не ошибки, а вывод сообщения о том, что выброшено исключения. Код полностью валидный.

Comment: С `xdebug` не сталкивался, буду знать, благодарю. Может все же не стоит отключать трэйс глобально? А убрать вызов исключения. И проверять к примеру так: `$search = new Search(); if( $search->$search_string===null ){ /*ошибка: пустой поисковый запрос*/ }`.

Comment: @borodatych у меня вся суть в исключении. Я логирываю все, что могу, при пустом запросе. Так как не уверен, что пользователь ввел пустой запрос, возможно строка потерялась из за манипуляций над ней. Это же PHP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: за это отвечает настройка `xdebug.show_exception_trace`, достаточно просто отключить ее. По расцветке также можно угадать, что это вывод xdebug, и в случае аналогичных непонятных происшествий начинать копать оттуда.

Сама по себе эта штука входит в пакет забавного функицонала xdebug (как минимум, есть еще `xdebug.sсream`, подавляющий оператор `@`), отвечающего за поиск архитектурных ошибок. Конкретно эта настройка позволяет найти все подавленные исключения и *покарать тех*, кто их проглатывает без обработки (идеальная программа должна работать без исключений вообще), но в продакшене и тестинге эта опция, конечно, должна быть отключена.

Answer (score -1):

Так тоже вылетает?

```
class Search
{
    public function __construct()
    {
      try {
        $this->db = Database::getInstance();

        // prepare search string
        $this->search_string = (isset($_GET['search']) && !empty($_GET['search']))? $_GET['search'] : null;
        if ($this->search_string === null) {
            throw new Exception(SEARCH_STRING_EMPTY, 99);
        }
        ...
      }
      catch (Exception $e) {
         echo $e->getMessage();
         ...
      }   
    }
}

$search = new Search();
```

UP
Запустил код вот в таком виде на PHP 5.5.15 и 5.4.31

```
<?php

class Search
{
    public function __construct()
    {
//        $this->db = Database::getInstance();

        // prepare search string
        $this->search_string = (isset($_GET['search']) && !empty($_GET['search']))? $_GET['search'] : null;
        if ($this->search_string === null) {
            throw new Exception("SEARCH_STRING_EMPTY", 99);
        }
//        ...
    }
}
try {
    $search = new Search();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
//    ...
}
```

Ни ошибок, ни предупреждений нет. Выводит только текст `SEARCH_STRING_EMPTY`

Comment: да, это было то что я первым делом попробывал, смысл в тот что php возврощает exeption как вроде это notice деление на 0, а после только срабатывает мой catch

Comment: Обновил свой пост.

Answer (score -2):

[Тут есть как решить проблему](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.exceptions.php) - `set_exception_handler()` или `finally`.

Comment: Что это и куда это?

Comment: скинул по зенду как закрыть, тебе же на чистом надо, исправил.

Comment: Попробовал, не какого эффекта не дало...
У меня ошибка вылетает не "Uncaught Exception: ...", а просто **"Exception: ..."**